# What is the type of this string and how to convert it to hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I passing ransack params from page to page. Initially params looks like hash

```rb
{"processed_at_gteq_datetime"=>"2021-08-01", "processed_at_lteq_datetime"=>"2021-09-14", "status_eq"=>"processed"}
```

But after sending this params to another page, it becomes a string and takes the following type:

```rb
"{\"processed_at_gteq_datetime\"=>\"2021-08-01\", \"processed_at_lteq_datetime\"=>\"2021-09-14\", \"status_eq\"=>\"processed\"}"
```

And in this form, I cannot use them for searching.

How i can convert this string:

```rb
"{\"processed_at_gteq_datetime\"=>\"2021-08-01\", \"processed_at_lteq_datetime\"=>\"2021-09-14\", \"status_eq\"=>\"processed\"}"
```

to hash?

I tried

```rb
JSON.parse my_params
```

But it doesn't work with this string

```
JSON::ParserError Exception: 767: unexpected token at '{"processed_at_gteq_datetime"=>"2021-08-01", "processed_at_lteq_datetime"=>"2021-09-14", "status_eq"=>"processed"}'
```

Comment: How did you "send these params to another page"?

Comment: The correct way to address this is not to try and parse Ruby code, but to figure out why the data got destroyed in the first place.#

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are passing parameters from page to page using either a link or a redirect.

If you want to keep those params as such, you have to pass them to the path helper:

```rb
link_to other_page_path(ransack_hash)
# => /other_page?processed_at_gteq_datetime=2021-08-01&processed_at_lteq_datetime=2021-09-14&status_eq=processed
```

and similar constructs. This

```rb
link_to other_page_path(q: ransack_hash)
# => /other_page?q[processed_at_gteq_datetime]=2021-08-01&q[processed_at_lteq_datetime]=2021-09-14&q[status_eq]=processed
```

will nest the params so that you can then retrieve in the other controller with

```
ransack_params = params[:q]
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason this doesn't work:

```rb
JSON.parse("{\"foo\"=>\"bar\"}")
```

is because it's not valid Json. for valid JSON you need to replace the ruby `=>` operator with the javascript `:` operator. You can do this with a ruby string manipulation.

```rb
string = "{\"foo\"=>\"bar\"}"
json = string.gsub(/=>/,':')
JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: This breaks, for example, for `string = '{"foo"=>"this is an arrow => that is part of the data, not the structure"}'`